# resizing time complexity - Chain Hashing with Dynamic Array

Tags: c++, hash, resize, time-complexity, dynamic-arrays

we built a hash table that is a dynamic array and each element in it is a linked list(chain hashing).

if each time we resize the hash table to be twice its original size, we obviously need to move all existing nodes in the chains, to the newly sized hash table, my question is: if we go through each linked list(the chains) -even the empty ones- does this change the complexity of amortized O(1)? if yes is going through the none empty linked lists a good solution(amortized time complexity of O(1))?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you maintain a [load factor](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/load-factor-and-rehashing/) of `x < 1` (A good default is keeping `0.25 < x < 0.5`, where `x` is the load factor), and you calculate it based on the number of elements in the hash table, you are fine.

You are going to iterate the table, which will take linear time (<4*n iterations), and this will take place after at least `1/4*n` operations - which means your amortized time is at worst `~4*n / (1/4*n) = 16`, which is still constant (This accounts for iterating over empty cells as well).